# Submitting to arXiv when unaffiliated

Tags: co.combinatorics, soft-question, journals, arxiv

I am writing a short paper in the area of combinatorics.

When the paper is complete, I would like to be able to submit it to arXiv.

The reasons that I would like to submit to arXiv are:

1. To obtain a date and time stamp from a central authority so that I can prove the work is mine.
2. To promote access to the paper under the Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike license

Although I have created an account on arXiv, because I am not affiliated to any academic institution, it appears that it might be difficult to get the paper accepted by arXiv.

For example see,

arxiv.org/help/submit

> The following information is also required for submission:
>
> Institutional affiliation for the
>   author(s) must be provided. Official
>   report number(s) from the author(s)
>   institution(s) must be provided.

Also the following blog article does not appear encouraging:

[Does The Arxiv Blacklist Authors ?](http://www.scientificblogging.com/quantum_diaries_survivor/does_arxiv_blacklist_authors_help_finding_out)

Does anyone on math*overflow* have any advice on how to submit to arXiv (or a similar database) without an academic affiliation?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments, which were all good and helpful.  The consensus seems that just endorsement without affiliation might suffice for the arXiv.  So I am going to complete my paper and check the result carefully.  After that, if I am confident that the result stands up, work out how to contact a respected member of the combinatorics community who might be happy to endorse my paper.  I am accepting Douglas' answer because of all the helpful comments.

Comment: I suggest that you also get one or two other people to check your work for both correctness and readability.

Comment:  One of my mentors,Dr.Melvyn Nathanson,is a HUGE advocate of publishing on Archive and he encourages everyone looking for a career in mathematics to begin publishing there.I could ask him about your question,Paul.

Comment: @Deanne - that response is kind of off topic - wont't vote it down - but I won't vote it up either.  Actually, once I get the time stamp sorted, I will probably just start a blog and try to build up a small following from zero.  Thankfully one does not need an endorser to open an account with Wordpress.

Comment: @Andrew - what is Archive?

Comment: @Paul: So, what happened?

Comment: @Gerald: I concluded that my original result was correct but irrelevant, so I decided not to publish it.  There is some other stuff that I am working on, but to start with I decided that I only really needed a blog with authorative time stamps.  arXiv appears to suggest to quite a lot of people close to journal quality.  I didn't feel confident that I could reach that level working on my own without any peer review.  Also, I wanted a lightweight process - the last think I want to be doing is bugging busy maths professors about endorsement. 

Comment: @Paul:  I agree with this criterion: put something on arXiv only if it is close to journal quality!  


Comment: If you want mathematicians to read your papers, you should bring them in "close to journal quality" anyway. I would suggest to focus on that - once you have achieved that, it shouldn't be too hard to find an endorser. (Note that the endorser isn't vouching for the correctness of the article.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need to be endorsed first.  See this link:  http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I'm not sure what the best way of going about this is (I have received completely unsolicited requests for endorsement and have turned them down on the grounds that the rules say that I must personally know the author.  In truth, if I were willing to vouch for the results of the manuscript to a reasonable degree, I would probably be willing to endorse it.)  You could post a link to your paper on some math forum (I'm not sure MO is the right place for this; maybe sci.math.research?) and you might find someone to endorse it.

Comment: @Douglas, thank you for your prompt answer.

I knew about the requirement to be endorsed.  The requirement to have academic affiliation seemed additional though.

@Pete - thank you for the suggestion.  I might resort to that - cross post to sci.math.research and MO with a summary of the paper and a link to a PDF, then see whether someone would be willing to endorse the paper for arXiv.  But even then there is the requirement for academic affiliation.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't need to be endorsed since I have an affiliation.  I'm afraid, I can't endorse (not enough papers).  you don't necessarily need to know the person, just check that their paper is not clap-trap:  "You should know the person that you endorse or you should see the paper that the person intends to submit."

Comment: @Paul: My guess is that you don't need academic affiliation if you have an endorsement. At least, like Douglas, I did have academic affiliation, and didn't need endorsement. Since endorsement seems to only be required without academic affiliation, it seems logical that you should not need to have both. 

Comment: @Grigoriev: When did you first register on arXiv?  My understanding was that all <i>new</i> users required endorsement, but there was an exemption for users registered before the cut off date.


Comment: @Paul: October 2009. I'm pretty sure I wasn't exempt.

Comment: I, too, think endorsement will suffice for those without academic affiliation.  When you try it, post in this thread and let us know what happened.

Comment: My first arXiv submisison was in July 2009; I have academic affiliation and didn't need endorsement.

Comment: Pete- from the arXiv help: "You should know the person that you endorse or you should see the paper that the person intends to submit."

Answer (score 27):

For your first goal (authoritative time stamp), check out [this site](http://www.itconsult.co.uk/stamper.htm).  Although it may not be well known, it maintains a good audit trail and should be pretty hard to contest.  It could also be useful for stamping work in progress, even if you are not ready to make it public.

Comment: Thanks +1 - would give you +10 if I could.  That is a very useful looking service and might fit my needs very well.

Answer (score 15):

It seems to be possible to submit a paper without being its author. If I remember it right, on the second page of the submission form, you have a question "Are you an author of the paper?" and "No" is an acceptable answer. So, you may just find somebody who is a "registered author" (this is just a technical term describing a person's relationship to the arXiv, not his relationship to the paper being submitted) and ask him to do the submission for you (of course, he'll want to look at what he's going to submit first but the authorship will remain exclusively yours though his name will appear in the "submitted by" field).

I agree that this "academic affiliation" thing is somewhat annoying but it is, probably, some sort of a safeguard against completely random people posting some total junk on arXiv. I guess it can be overridden by the arXiv administrators on a case by case basis but my guess would also be that to do this, they should be first convinced that what you are going to post is a high quality stuff. So, before writing to them, it would be nice to have a few papers published somewhere and a few known people to certify that you aren't just one more crank, which creates some sort of catch 22 in your situation.

Comment: Thank you.  That's a very considered answer.  I agree a balance needs to be struck.  Perhaps academic affiliation is no absolute guarantee of quality though.  What I might end up doing is posting a  summary of the paper here on MO with a link to a PDF somewhere.  Then the reputation of MO can work its magic.  If the consensus is that the paper <i>is</i> junk then I will just let it fade away.  On the other hand, if the consensus is generally favorable, then probably someone will be willing to endorse and submit for me.



Comment: @Paul, just make sure if you post on MO about your paper, you do so as a good question! We *don't* want questions of the form "What do you think of my paper", or any variations, thank you! :-)

Comment: @Scott - OK understood - I will be sure to respect that.  I was new to MO at that point and did not fully understand the ground rules.

Comment: The academic affiliation appears to be optional: it may allow to bypass the need for endorsement and thus streamline the process. As for the authorship, I imagine that the intent was to allow researchers to delegate this kind of tedious submission to their subordinates. 

Answer (score 14):

> Official report number(s) from the author(s) institution(s) must be provided.

I have absolutely no idea what that phrase means. I have a few papers on the arXiv and have never knowingly provided that information.  With the proviso that I'm not privy to the internal workings of the arXiv, I would recommend just trying to submit and seeing what it tells you to do - I deem it highly unlikely that you'll get a message saying "You have no affiliation, never darken our doors again!" but more likely "We notice that you have not provided an academic affiliation; therefore, in order for your article to be properly submitted, you need to do X, Y, and Z.".

There are, of course, other ways of getting timestamps and of making your work public.  If you want to know whether or not it is of sufficient quality to be worth publishing, you should track down someone in the field who you could ask for an opinion.

(But if you do that, **don't** just send them the manuscript with a brief note saying "Please give me your opinion on the attached."!  Write a specific letter to that person, preferably with a fair amount of flattery - don't overdo it - and ask a specific question.  If you want to know "Has this been done before", you could ask that here, I think, but if you want to know "Is this decent quality work", then you should not ask it here.)

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the advice - much appreciated.

Comment: I posted papers to the arXiv for the first time last month and just left the "Official report number(s) from the author(s) institution(s)" entry blank. Although at arxiv.org/help/submit it seems that it is required to enter some sort of report number, when you actually get there it seems to say to enter it only if it exists. Perhaps a better way to say it is that you should enter a official institution report number if and only if such a number exists. My guess is that they ask for this so that appropriate credit/sourcing/whatever is given to the institution. Maybe.

Comment: @Philip - +1 for the report on your experince with the arXiv 

Comment: I've seen many institutions, especially in Europe, that produce preprints for their researchers. I believe that's what the report number refers to, a way to give proper credit the way you do it by adding the journal info. Of course, these kind of reports are remnants of a bygone era, but I bet you'll see this field for a while still.

Answer (score 6):

Normally you need an endorser for arXiv.org but that is not always necessary or sufficient. Try writing to the administrators if you are stuck. If all else fails and you need it archived with a datestamp use viXra.org which was set up for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Thanks - I did not know about viXra.org - so +1 for that alone.  In fact, the datestamp is what I want most.  One strategy would be to (1) get a datestamped PDF online with viXra.org, (2) use the online PDF to seek an endorser for arXiv.org.  Another strategy would to be support viXra.org's principled support of open science by not bothering with step (2).  viXra.org plus a trusted reputation system (like mathoverflow) layered on top would be pretty compelling in my view. Food for thought anyway.

Comment: I would suggest against using viXra -- I don't know how widely known it is, but I think you should worry much more that associating with it gets you ignored as a crank than that your work is so brilliant that the mathematicians you send it to try to steal it.

As Phil said in the thread you linked: "Perhaps viXra will catch on and show that an open submission policy is not something to fear. At first they will probably laugh at some of what it contains, but when people find themselves citing e-prints in viXra they may finally get the point."  I think we are still in the "at first" stage.

Comment: Incidentally, the "Does the arXiv blacklist authors?" thread is clearly irrelevant to you -- as far as I can tell, everyone on that thread whose subject matter was not related to Mary Magdalene and who hadn't previously tried to evade arXiv moderators was able to successfully get their work up.

Comment: @JBL from http://vixra.org/why " Firstly, many amateur scientists are just trying to do ordinary science. They do not have to make the next great paradigm shift in science before their work can be useful."  That's right - I'm not claiming to have proved/disproved the Riemann Hypothesis - just _trying_ to do good solid maths/science outside of traditional academia.

Comment: @JBL re: cranks problem - that is why I wrote about the need for a trusted (MO like) reputation system layered on top.  MO reputation looks to me _better_ than traditional peer review.  The average standard of the Wikipedia maths article looks to me _better_ than the average maths paper on arXiv.org.  Furthermore, (1) the trusted reputation system could evolve later after a reasonable archive of datestamped articles had built up (2) it could be external to and not exclusive to viXra.org.  (It could _be_ the MO reputation system _if_ MO wanted to evolve that way.) 

Comment: @Paul, I'm not sure it what way your first comment is a response to me.  I encourage you to continue your mathematical work -- I just think that you should avoid viXra if you don't want to be labeled (incorrectly) as a crank.

Comment: There is no reason why anyone should consider you a crank because you use viXra.org. There are many papers there that have been published in peer-reviewed journals. There are also many cranky papers on arXiv.org. People post on viXra.org because for some reason they can't or don't want to use arXiv.org, not because they are cranks. Some people use both. 

Comment: @JBL - you wrote ".. than that your work is so brilliant that ..." hence my quote from vixra.org.  Also I agree with Phil Gibbs - I think you are scaremongering about viXra.org.

Comment: I never saw a high-quality article on viXra.org, maybe someone can give an example. I saw article on arXiv, though, which was so wrong that you can literally give it to your "real analysis" students and ask them as an exercise to find the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

**Official Report Number** tends to stand for internal numbers assigned by the University or Research Institution for **Technical Reports**.  For example, ATT Bell Labs often published their internal research documents as Technical Reports, and the Computer Science department at M.I.T. also tends to publish internal research findings, often supported by government sources or sponsored-research funded by corportations, as "white papers" or technical reports.

MIT's library is pretty good at finding these things: http://libguides.mit.edu/techreports, and their webpage defines technical reports as

#### What is a technical report?

Technical reports:

- Are written to convey new developments or final results of scientific and technical research.
- Are usually funded by government departments or corporate bodies.
- Deliver technical information to the funding organization.
- Provide a forum for peer information exchange.
- Are not easy to find

---

Also, a lot of research funded by the military or DARPA or the OSD in the United States has a **Final Report** as its ultimate end-result and the means of disseminating the findings and recommendations, rather than a peer-reviewed journal article.

It is a shame that have an educational e-mail address for affiliation gets you a bye for submitting to arxiv; perhaps even academics should need an endorsement prior to being allowed to commit an article to arxiv.  The seed recommenders would have to have been planted earlier, anyway.