# Downsides of using the arXiv?  

Tags: arxiv, journals, soft-question

Not to sound like a [refusenik](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=113928457) or a [contrarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrarian), but I have always been a bit of an agnostic when it comes to the [arXiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv). Somewhere deep in my old [Pine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_(e-mail_client)) folders there is a 15 y.o. discussion with Greg Kuperberg on the subject, and it seems the history proved him right - the arXiv is now incredibly valuable and popular (perhaps, even a little too popular, see below).  However, despite all the benefits, I think posting on the arXiv is a serious decision, often enough a good idea, but not always, and definitely not without downside as Matthew Daws [writes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64982/publishing-journals-articles-without-transferring-copyright) (to a wide 27+ support):

> But, definitely use the arxiv! I don't see any downside to putting a preprint on the arxiv; and it might lead to more people reading your work and hence more recognition.

While benefits of the arXiv are well known and understood, as evidenced by the [growth in the volume of submissions](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/simeon/pubs/FC2005/arXiv_history.pdf), I believe negative aspects are somewhat less known.  Thus, my question:

**Do you know any downsides of using the arXiv?**

If yes, tell us what are they.  Is there a story behind?  If no, say nothing, of course. I start with a few (mostly minor) quips below to get this started (see also [here](http://quantumbiodiscs.blogspot.com/2007/03/should-i-publish-research-ideas-on-my.html) for a rare critical blog post in another field).

---

1)  If you are a graduate student or a junior faculty, you might not be as fast as others in developing your own ideas.  As soon as you post early results which use your new ideas, they become a fair game. Now someone else can recognize their value and quickly solve your main problem before you are half way through.  On the other hand, going the more traditional print publication route would give a couple of years cushion, sufficient in most cases.

2)  On a related subject of *destructive competition*, arXiv can be really unhelpful.  One graduate student I know liked a conjecture posed in an arXiv preprint.  He solved it in about two months.  When he was finishing writing his solution, somebody posted an identical solution.  He was quite distressed.  Another graduate student I know, discovered two weeks before the Ph.D. defense that the main result in her thesis was just posted on the arXiv in a more general form by a senior faculty elsewhere.  Upon insistence of her advisor, she cancelled the defense and left academia without a Ph.D. degree.

3)  An obvious point:  some/many arXiv preprints are incorrect, leading to questions like [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41141/should-i-not-cite-an-arxiv-org-paper).  This creates a bizarre "neither solved nor open" status: while a solution of an important problem is being checked, no one wants to work on the problem.  On rare occasions, [two opposite solutions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26821/is-thompsons-group-f-amenable) are posted leading to partial paralysis in the field.  BTW, [plagiarism](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0702012) is yet another variation on this issue (here the *authorship* is incorrect).

4)  The other side of the same coin: if a person (like one friend of mine) posts an incorrect solution of a famous problem, this creates too much attention, potentially destroying a career (esp if in the early stages).

5)  The "[unaffiliated people problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12894/submitting-to-arxiv-when-unaffiliated)" which makes it hard from people from third world countries, as well as anonymous authors to contribute (not everyone is as brave as Mnёv, see my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51056/are-there-any-good-websites-for-hosting-discussions-of-mathematical-papers)).  While arXiv's restrictions do help get rid of some [cranks](http://ftp.resource.org/courts.gov/c/F3/75/75.F3d.307.95-2282.html), there are [other ways](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=458) to do that, and one can argue that one gem from an unaffiliated author is worth 100 crank papers.

6)  Some people [apparently](http://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/reader-survey-do-you-follow-the-arxiv/) read arXiv every day.  Really?  One friend of mine (in physics) admitted to me he spends 1.5-2 hours every morning doing that.  Really???

7)  ArXiv's success also has downsides, as it increases pressure on young mathematicians to post, so as to [keep up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_up_with_the_Joneses) with others, even if their natural instinct in some cases maybe is to be protective of their ideas and further develop them before making them public.  The social pressure can be quite strong, as hiring committees increasingly view arXiv preprints as "near publications".  More anecdotally, one senior mathematician I know likes to ask people "What's your most recent arXiv paper?" in place of a more traditional "What are you working on?" as if arXiv posting is a "must do" for everyone.

8)  An indirect and less obvious downside:  arXiv's success clearly slowed down rather than sped up the natural tendency to bypass traditional print publishers for electronic media, as there is less of a pressure to have all journals *nearly free* and *widely accessible*. This is contrary to the [early predictions](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/tragic.loss.update) which expected for the transition to happen before 2010.

Comment: Am I being extremely naive, or was the advisor in (2) being perverse? It happens that the same unsolved problem gets worked on by multiple people, and it seems commonplace to credit everyone who solved it independently. This seems especially true if the second person to announce is far junior to the first. IMHO, someone should have fought, *hard*, for that student. 

Comment: I think the question is potentially valuable (and certainly a valid one) but find some of Igor's deliberately provocative "quips" or examples stretch the argument too much. The question should be CW, though.

Comment: I'm sure that there is a valuable discussion to be had here.  On the other hand, I strongly suspect that said discussion should not be had on MathOverflow.  I have further thoughts on the matter, but will move them to http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1048/downsides-of-the-arxiv/ , which is a better forum than the comments here for discussing appropriateness of questions.

Comment: I vote to close as "subjective and argumentative". The reason is that we don't have a reality without ArXiv to compare to. The notion of "downside" is a relative notion, and does not make sense without reference to an other reality, without ArXiv. But what would that reality look like?...

Comment: @André - the question is whether there is a downside of *using* the arXiv.  For example, just because wide majority of people drive to work, the "you should buy a car" advice might not be applicable to everyone and all circumstances.  While I am definitely *not* advocating not to use arXiv, I wonder if using it is taken a bit too axiomatic.  

Comment: Half the time I don't bother with the arxiv. It's easier just to post preprints on my web page. Doing that (or even distributing preprints by mail, or whatever) doesn't change any of the "problems" you mention. The arxiv is a fact of life and your question is seriously subjective and argumentative. Voting to close. 

Comment: Voting to close as "subjective and argumentative". Everything has a downside including sex, good food, internet, and yes, even the arXiv. I do not think MO is the right place for such provocative discussions. 

Comment: @André: I'm surprised you question what a reality could be without the arXiv. Consider the many years of mathematical research *before* the arXiv was developed, or at least the period from 1950 until the arXiv came about. 

Comment: @Igor: On the meta page, peter.krautzberger points out that there _is_ a good place for such discussions.  Namely, I encourage you to make sure your blog is visible to Mathblogging.org/planetMO, and to move this discussion there.  It's not that I don't like this discussion in the abstract --- I don't like it on MO.  But you could support Mathblogging.org/planetMO and have a forum for discussion at the same time.

Comment: @Felipe: ouch! Please do bother with the arXiv! :)

Comment: This is kind of like "What is the downside of the internet?"...

Comment: I can see why this was closed; but at the same time, it's a bit of a shame not to get a right of reply!  Igor-- please do think about getting this on a blog somehow.  I do happen to think most (if not all) of these are rather poor points.  But I can add some other downsides: 9) You cannot delete from the arXiv (perhaps related to (4)). 10) People will cite your arxiv preprint, and not the final published version, so you "loose" the citation.

Comment: This question is important but isn't suitable for MO.

Comment: Ben Webster has made a blog post about this, available here: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/what-are-the-downsides-of-the-arxiv

Answer (score 51):

There is no downside to arXiv.  If you don't want to post a paper there, then don't.  If you don't want to read papers on arXiv or to study the daily collection of abstracts of papers just posted, then don't.  Nor is there any issue of plagiarism of ideas from arXiv that is different from plagiarism from a journal article.  To publish an article means to make it public.  A manuscript uploaded to arXiv is a publicly accessible and, therefore, a published manuscript, with the author's name attached to all the ideas, theorems, proofs, and conjectures that the paper contains.

There is also an important democratizing aspect of arXiv.  In many fields of mathematics, preprints used to be circulated privately among a small group of insiders and their students.  It was difficult for outsiders to learn about new results and problems, and to "break into" the club.  It was essentially impossible for mathematicians in many poor countries to have access to research papers; the mathematicians were isolated and their universities could not afford journal subscriptions.  Now all they need is internet access to find out about current research.  The establishment of arXiv as a central repository for preprints in all fields of mathematics is an extraordinarily significant accomplishment, and will have a profound impact on the future of mathematics.

Comment: Yeah, I expected this kind of answer.  This is sort of like saying that TV has no downside.  Indeed, you don't have to watch nor let you kids watch it, if you don't want to.  Well, TV is a great invention, watching is great in many cases, but it's not like we shouldn't ask any questions about its potential downsides, like this one: http://bit.ly/15pMaN Same with the internet - great, terrific, democratizing, etc. but people still ask questions:  http://bit.ly/auls1u  

Comment: Even as someone who would strongly defend the claim "On the whole, the net effect of the arXiv is very positive" I think it obviously silly to say that there is no possibility of any downside at all. All of your arguments for why the arXiv is good are completely right, but I don't think that rules out there being downsides too.

Comment: What I mean is that many important inventions have positive effects greatly outweighing the negative.  But just like with prescription drugs, informed users should learn the negatives even if they are rare or relatively minor.  For example Penicillin is a great drug, but...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penicillin_drug_reaction  Saying "if you don't want to use Penicillin, you don't have to" is really unhelpful. 

Comment: One apparent downside is this discussion: if there were no ArXiV, we wouldn't argue about it here. In general, I think the main downside is the same as it was for the invention of writing, paper, bookprinting, typewriters, TeX, internet, etc.: all of them make it easier for, erm, "low quality posters" to flood the information channels with junk. If you want me to be more serious, there are no downsides of tools, just downsides of people using them. Ben's comment says, essentially, that "everything can and will be misused". I agree wholeheartedly, but so what?

Comment: You make some very good points, but it's not an answer to the question. The question is about downsides of *using* the arXiv, not about downsides of [the existence of] the arXiv.

Comment: +1 for the "democratizing aspect"